# Sufficient conditions for map to be open

Tags: real-analysis

Reading Apostol's "Mathematical Analysis", I came across the following theorem, regarding sufficient conditions for a mapping to be open:

> Let $A$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and assume $f:A\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous with finite partial derivatives on $A$. If $f$ is 1-1 on $A$ and if $J_f(x)\neq 0$ on $A$, then $f(A)$ is open.

I tried to play around with the theorem, to see how necessary the hypotheses are. I considered a 1 dimensional case for simplicity, and $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto x^3$, which is 1-1 on $(-1,1)$ but which has a Jacobian (in this one dimensional case simply the derivative) zero on $0\in (-1,1)$. In this case I seem to have $f[(-1,1)]$ open. So I am not convinced about the necessity of $J_f\neq 0$ in the hypothesis of the theorem.

What am I missing? Is the point $0$ special in any way? Is not the image still $(-1,1)$ which is open?

Comment: Nowhere this theorem tell that $J_f(x)$ **must** be different from $0$ for $f(A)$ to be open.

Comment: You yourself answered the question in the title: this just gives a **sufficient** condition, not a *necessary* one.

Comment: @cronos2 His hypotheses are two: 1-1 on A and Jacobian non-zero on $A$. Why would he include the non-zero Jacobian in his hypotheses, if it need not be there to conclude that $f(A)$ be open?

Comment: Well, actually he assumes $f$ is continuous and has finite partial derivatives too. None of the four is necessary for the statement to be true, but you can't conclude anything if you don't impose conditions to the functions. They may not be *optimal*, but that doesn't mean you're lying.

Comment: Please note the difference between a "if ... then" clause and an "if and only if" one

Comment: Well, his theorem would be "stronger" if he had assumed less. I do not understand why he would assume a "redundant" thing and hence make his theorem weaker.

Comment: By invariance of domain, continuous and injective suffices to imply open. But that's a hammer one doesn't have when first learning analysis, one learns about that in topology. The given assumptions make for an easy proof, and that's valuable. Also these conditions are very often satisfied by the functions one considers in analysis. So it's quite useful. The stronger version doesn't buy you that much more that investing the time needed to prove it is well-spent in this context.